# Populate items on listview after each x seconds

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a method that detects beacons after each 30 seconds. The scenario is as follows:

1. The scan period of beacons is 60 seconds.
2. The waiting period before the next scan is 30 seconds.

The above settings have already been defined in the `BeaconDectector` class. Now to display the beacons scanned on my UI, I have the following:

```
 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {       
    bool start = true; 
    while (start) {
       beaconsFound = StartDetection(); 
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                  {
                      listView.ItemsSource = beaconsFound;

                  });
    }
 }
```

The `StartDetection` contains the logic that take place every 30 seconds and the scan period is 60 seconds. How can I ensure that I don't miss any beacons to get displayed on my listview?

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Use a Timer object and have it trigger the logic to fetch the beacons.

Comment: The StartDetection() contains a listener that does the scanning for 60 secs and wait for 30 secs to do another scan cycle. How can I keep the StartDetection() running then ?

Comment: Does your listview have an adapter? For updating listview you should call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after it's dataSource changed.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely not use active waiting `while(start)` to manage this. A better solution would be a `Timer`. You can see the basics for this in [this blogpost](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-timer/).

Furthermore, ensure you are not running any long running code on the UI thread (which is what `Button_Clicked` runs on). Ideally, your timer should fire each 30 seconds, start a new `Task` for the detection and use `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` to update the list when appropriate.

Comment: Hello. Bu this `StartDetection()` method fires an event every 30 seconds. 

What if I create a method which is recursive and calls itself after 30 seconds using `Task.Delay(3000)` ? Do you think its a good idea?

Comment: The `StartDetection()` contains a listener that does the scanning for 60 secs and wait for 30 secs to do another scan cycle. How can I keep the `StartDetection()` running then ?